# Multiple Instances of same Microservices should not fetch and update same MongoDB Documents

Tags: spring, mongodb, transactions, microservices

**Problem Statement:**

There is one Scheduler in our microservice which will fetch 10 Request Documents(having staus "A") and start processing on them and after that update each Document's status.

We are planning to deploy three instances of the same microservice. once all three instances start executing scheduler then each instance will fetch 10 Request Documents and start processing them.

**The same request documents should not be fetched and processed in multiple instances. How can I make sure that each instance of microservice picks 10 different documents?**

Answer (score 1):

Each of your workers should choose a different set of documents.

For example, if you have an autoincrement numeric id for your documents:

- Worker 1 can get all documents where ID % 3 = 0
- Worker 2 can get all documents where ID % 3 = 1
- Worker 3 can get all documents where ID % 3 = 2

If autoincrement ID is not available, you can take a look at consistent hashing which is very nice to learn.

Hashing is simple:

1. Compute the hash of the document ID
2. Use this hash to get which worker should process this document

The problem with this approach is that, say the range of your document ID hash is between 1 and 1000 and you are using the same approach above. You might end up by Worker 1 getting much more work than worker 2.

With Consistent Hashing, you expand the range to get a more balanced.

Comment: autoincrement ID is not available. Could you please provide some good references for "consistent hashing"?

Comment: I have edited the response. I advise you to start with simple hashing. Just hash the document ID and then use the modulo example that I gave you. If you want to do the extra step, you can use consistent hashing. It is available all over the internet.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the solution, it's quite good but in my scenario, we don't have numeric Ids. I was expecting some solutions related to MongoDB transactions. Fetching criteria would be the only Request Status.

Comment: @DevChauhan Did you get any solution?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this race condition ?